# How do you use TypeApplications in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, ghc, language-extension

With `-XTypeApplications` in GHC 8.0, you can specify types explicitly with `@` preceding function arguments. What types does it exactly specify, especially when several `@` are introduced?

Comment: I think it's a good idea to use `ExplicitForAll` (or `TypedScopeVariables` which subsumes it) if you intend to use `TypeApplications`, since in that case there's no ambiguity: if you have e.g. `const :: forall a b. a -> b -> a`, then the first `@`-argument will be for the `a`, and the second one for the `b`.

Comment: `ScopedTypeVariables`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you look at the type of a function

```
elem :: (Foldable t, Eq a) => a -> t a -> Bool
```

we see it has two polymorphic variables, `t` and `a`. These variables are what the `@` type applications specify. It seems that variables introduced in the context — where typeclass constraints go — affect order, and hence the first `@` specifies the `t`, and the second the `a`. In functions without context variables

```
const :: a -> b -> a
```

the order is more obvious, the `a` is first and `b` is second. As Cactus mentioned in a comment above, you can also use explicit foralls to specify the order yourself.

```
myConst :: forall b a. a -> b -> a
```

Now the first type application will specify the `b` and the second the `a`.

You may run into this problem of needing to specify types particularly if you're using overloaded strings or lists

```
elem c "abc...xyz" -- What string type is this?
elem c ['a' .. 'z'] -- What list constructor is this?
```

therefore we use explicit type applications

```
elem @[] @Char c ['a' .. 'z']
```

in this case we only *have* to specify the `@[]` and say "this is a `[]` list type constructor" because GHC infers `Char` from the list elements, so `@Char` can be omitted here.

If a polymorphic argument GHC is able to infer happens to come first you can leverage `-XPartialTypeSignatures` which allows you to use `_` in type signatures including type application signatures, telling GHC to just infer that [part of the] type, to make things less verbose.

```
f @_ @[]
```

Comment: To me it seems that after more than one type application any readability benefit compared to `::` is gone, especially since one has to recall the type constraint order. At least in this case, I'd consider `elem c ['a' .. 'z'] :: [Char]` to be far more readable.