# Besides as-pattern, what else can @ mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, symbols, operator-keyword, as-pattern

I am studying Haskell currently and try to understand a project that uses Haskell to implement cryptographic algorithms. After reading *Learn You a Haskell for Great Good* online, I begin to understand the code in that project. Then I found I am stuck at the following code with the "@" symbol:

```
-- | Generate an @n@-dimensional secret key over @rq@.
genKey :: forall rq rnd n . (MonadRandom rnd, Random rq, Reflects n Int)
       => rnd (PRFKey n rq)
genKey = fmap Key $ randomMtx 1 $ value @n
```

Here the randomMtx is defined as follows:

```
-- | A random matrix having a given number of rows and columns.
randomMtx :: (MonadRandom rnd, Random a) => Int -> Int -> rnd (Matrix a)
randomMtx r c = M.fromList r c <$> replicateM (r*c) getRandom
```

And PRFKey is defined below:

```
-- | A PRF secret key of dimension @n@ over ring @a@.
newtype PRFKey n a = Key { key :: Matrix a }
```

All information sources I can find say that @ is the as-pattern, but this piece of code is apparently not that case. I have checked the online tutorial, blogs and even *the Haskell 2010 language report* at https://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell2010.pdf. There is simply no answer to this question.

More code snippets can be found in this project using @ in this way too:

```
-- | Generate public parameters (\( \mathbf{A}_0 \) and \(
-- \mathbf{A}_1 \)) for @n@-dimensional secret keys over a ring @rq@
-- for gadget indicated by @gad@.
genParams :: forall gad rq rnd n .
            (MonadRandom rnd, Random rq, Reflects n Int, Gadget gad rq)
          => rnd (PRFParams n gad rq)
genParams = let len = length $ gadget @gad @rq
                n   = value @n
            in Params <$> (randomMtx n (n*len)) <*> (randomMtx n (n*len))
```

I deeply appreciate any help on this.

Comment: These are [type applications](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/type-application). See also [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40275080/how-do-you-use-typeapplications-in-haskell). You can also look at the [commit](https://github.com/cpeikert/Lol/commit/75e44aaec43f8c278268f2ffbb2cb029f3231991) that introduced them into the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links! These are exactly what I am looking for. Surprisingly, you even identify the commit of the code! Many thanks for that. Just curious about how do you find it? @MikaelF

Comment: Github has its own interface to [git blame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203001/what-does-git-blame-do), which will tell you in which commit each line was last modified.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this useful tip:)

Comment: Why the at-command tag?

Comment: Because @ also pronounces "at" in the email address...

Comment: @SigurdW Thank you for raising the quality of questions for the `haskell` tag. I got a lot out of it.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard Very glad you can benefit from it. I am grateful to kind people spending time to help me out. Hope the answer can also help others.

Comment: @SigurdW at-command tag refers to AT commands, a serial interface used to communicate with modems, so I'm afraid it is not relevant in this question.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni Yes, thanks for your correction.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That `@n` is an advanced feature of modern Haskell, which is usually not covered by tutorials like LYAH, nor can be found the the Report.

It's called a [type application](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html?highlight=typeapplications#extension-TypeApplications) and is a GHC language extension. To understand it, consider this simple polymorphic function

```
dup :: forall a . a -> (a, a)
dup x = (x, x)
```

Intuitively calling `dup` works as follows:

- the *caller* chooses a *type* `a`
- the *caller* chooses a *value* `x` of the previously chosen type `a`
- `dup` then answers with a value of type `(a,a)`

In a sense, `dup` takes two arguments: the type `a` and the value `x :: a`. However, GHC is usually able to infer the type `a` (e.g. from `x`, or from the context where we are using `dup`), so we usually pass only one argument to `dup`, namely `x`. For instance, we have

```
dup True    :: (Bool, Bool)
dup "hello" :: (String, String)
...
```

Now, what if we want to pass `a` explicitly? Well, in that case we can turn on the `TypeApplications` extension, and write

```
dup @Bool True      :: (Bool, Bool)
dup @String "hello" :: (String, String)
...
```

Note the `@...` arguments carrying types (not values). Those are something that exists at compile time, only -- at runtime the argument does not exist.

Why do we want that? Well, sometimes there is no `x` around, and we want to prod the compiler to choose the right `a`. E.g.

```
dup @Bool   :: Bool -> (Bool, Bool)
dup @String :: String -> (String, String)
...
```

Type applications are often useful in combination with some other extensions which make type inference unfeasible for GHC, like ambiguous types or type families. I won't discuss those, but you can simply understand that sometimes you really need to help the compiler, especially when using powerful type-level features.

Now, about your specific case. I don't have all the details, I don't know the library, but it's very likely that your `n` represents a kind of natural-number value *at the type level*. Here we are diving in rather advanced extensions, like the above-mentioned ones plus `DataKinds`, maybe `GADTs`, and some typeclass machinery. While I can't explain everything, hopefully I can provide some basic insight. Intuitively,

```
foo :: forall n . some type using n
```

takes as argument `@n`, a kind-of compile-time natural, which is not passed at runtime. Instead,

```
foo :: forall n . C n => some type using n
```

takes `@n` (compile-time), together with a *proof* that `n` satisfies constraint `C n`. The latter is a run-time argument, which might expose the actual value of `n`. Indeed, in your case, I guess you have something vaguely resembling

```
value :: forall n . Reflects n Int => Int
```

which essentially allows the code to bring the type-level natural to the term-level, essentially accessing the "type" as a "value". (The above type is considered an "ambiguous" one, by the way -- you really need `@n` to disambiguate.)

Finally: why should one want to pass `n` at the type level if we then later on convert that to the term level? Wouldn't be easier to simply write out functions like

```
foo :: Int -> ...
foo n ... = ... use n
```

instead of the more cumbersome

```
foo :: forall n . Reflects n Int => ...
foo ... = ... use (value @n)
```

The honest answer is: yes, it would be easier. However, having `n` at the type level allows the compiler to perform more static checks. For instance, you might want a type to represent "integers modulo `n`", and allow adding those. Having

```
data Mod = Mod Int  -- Int modulo some n

foo :: Int -> Mod -> Mod -> Mod
foo n (Mod x) (Mod y) = Mod ((x+y) `mod` n)
```

works, but there is no check that `x` and `y` are of the same modulus. We might add apples and oranges, if we are not careful. We could instead write

```
data Mod n = Mod Int  -- Int modulo n

foo :: Int -> Mod n -> Mod n -> Mod n
foo n (Mod x) (Mod y) = Mod ((x+y) `mod` n)
```

which is better, but still allows to call `foo 5 x y` even when `n` is not `5`. Not good. Instead,

```
data Mod n = Mod Int  -- Int modulo n

-- a lot of type machinery omitted here

foo :: forall n . SomeConstraint n => Mod n -> Mod n -> Mod n
foo (Mod x) (Mod y) = Mod ((x+y) `mod` (value @n))
```

prevents things to go wrong. The compiler statically checks everything. The code is harder to use, yes, but in a sense making it harder to use is the whole point: we want to make it impossible for the user to try adding something of the wrong modulus.

Concluding: these are very advanced extensions. If you're a beginner, you will need to slowly progress towards these techniques. Don't be discouraged if you can't grasp them after only a short study, it does take some time. Make a small step at a time, solve some exercises for each feature to understand the point of it. And you'll always have StackOverflow when you are stuck :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation! It really solves my problem, and I guess I would need much more time to find the answer myself. Also thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Link is broken but I think it's this page: https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/type_applications.html