# What does the @ symbol do within an expression in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to figure out what `@` does in an expression like `endpoint @"start"`. Is it part of a language extension perhaps?

I see the follow extensions enabled for the module the function is in.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds                  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric              #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DerivingStrategies         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase                 #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RecordWildCards            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies               #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators              #-}
```

The full function:

```
endpoints :: Contract () AuctionSchema Text ()
endpoints = (start' `select` bid' `select` close') >> endpoints
  where
    start' = endpoint @"start" >>= start
    bid'   = endpoint @"bid"   >>= bid
    close' = endpoint @"close" >>= close
```

Comment: This is `-XTypeApplications` combined with type-level string literals.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two relevant extensions' documentation to read: [`TypeApplications`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/type_applications.html#extension-TypeApplications) and [`DataKinds`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/data_kinds.html#extension-DataKinds). A snippet from the type applications documentation:

> The `TypeApplications` extension allows you to use visible type application in expressions. Here is an example: `show (read @Int "5")`. The `@Int` is the visible type application; it specifies the value of the type variable in `read`'s type.

And from the data kinds documentation:

> With `DataKinds`, GHC automatically promotes every datatype to be a kind and its (value) constructors to be type constructors.

I guess you sort of also have to know about `Symbol`, a type-level representation of strings that is more efficient (but less featureful) than type-level `[Char]`, but I couldn't find a good place in the official documentation to read about it. You can read about it some in the [`GHC.TypeLits` haddocks](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html).

Comment: Thanks, yes seems to be correct. Related answer to this is also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61482257/besides-as-pattern-what-else-can-mean-in-haskell